# Edge is not able to parse VTT file generated by AMS v3

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, caption, webvtt, vtt

The VTT generated by AMS v3 has some “NOTE” in the top of the vtt file. Edge and IE11 Browsers are complaining about it. It throws below parsing error. Same VTT files works fine in Chrome and firefox.

> MEDIA12608: WebVTT Text Track: Timestamp signature should be '-->'. hr=80004004.

If we remove the following “NOTE” from top, the same vtt works fine on Edge and IE11.

NOTE

duration:"00:10:07.0110000"

language:en-US

NOTE Confidence: 0.911574065685272

It seems like multiple line comment is causing problem here. Below are different permutations I've tried cases where we get errors. In 1st and 3rd case I'm getting error but in 2nd and 4th case I'm not getting any error. So it seems like if we are having multiline comment in VTT file Edge and IE11 is throwing error.

1.

WEBVTT

NOTE 
duration:”00:10:07.0110000”
language:en-US

NOTE Confidence: 0.911574065685272

2.

WEBVTT

NOTE Confidence: 0.911574065685272

3.

WEBVTT

NOTE  duration:"00:10:07.0110000"
language:en-US

NOTE Confidence: 0.911574065685272

4.

WEBVTT

NOTE duration:"00:10:07.0110000"

NOTE language:en-US

NOTE Confidence: 0.911574065685272

Please let me know if someone have nny suggestions or work around to fix the issue in Edge and IE11?

Comment: [Related standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/webvtt1/#webvtt-comment-block) for anyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with MS Edge and I am able to produce the issue.

I find that this error can occur in various conditions. Like here you are getting an error with comments but if you use the style cue than also this error can occur.

```
WEBVTT

NOTE duration:”00:10:07.0110000” language:en-US

NOTE Confidence: 0.911574065685272
```

Below is my testing result.

[image]

[Tested code link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mHCPL2QECBoV9PHx?preview&p=preview)

I find some other docs and I got this link. In that link other user got similar error.

[STYLE cue on WebVTT prevents subtitle rendering](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17128999/)

In which it was mentioned by the MS Edge Team that:

> This issue has been resolved External. This means this issue may
>   require a new feature to be implemented or other work that is more
>   significant than a typical bug. You may be able to find more
>   information on this issue by searching for related features on
>   status.microsoftedge.com and uservoice.microsoftedge.com.

As per my understanding, this will get fixed in [New MS Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/).

Comment: Thanks Deepak-MSFT. Is thee any workaround ? If i don't want to wait for the update from Microsoft and fix the issue asap.

Comment: I tried to search but did not got any work around. I will try to provide you if I will get any solution or work around in future. Thanks for your understanding.